# How arrange datetime format

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, openerp-7, odoo-9

I have two fields as shown below.

```
>  appo_date = fields.Date(string="Appointment Date")
>  appo_time = fields.Float(string="Appointment Time")
```

I concatenated the two fields.

```
@api.multi
    def _combine(self):
        if self.appo_date and self.appo_time:
            self.appo_date_and_time = '%s  %f' % (self.appo_date, self.appo_time)
        elif self.appo_date:
            self.appo_date_and_time = str(self.appo_date)
        elif self.appo_time:
            self.appo_date_and_time = str(self.appo_time)
```

And called that function in a separate field as shown below.

```
appo_date_and_time = fields.Char(compute='_combine', string='Appointment Date/Time', arg=('appo_date','appo_time'), method=True)
```

These fields are called in xml files

```
<field name="appo_date"/>
<field name="appo_time"/>
<field name="appo_date_and_time"/>
```

I am getting output as

```
'2016-05-19  9.00000'
```

In this format. I need it `19/05/2016 9:00`

How to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *split* function of string object.

Try with this code.

```
string_obj_name.split(' ')[0]
```

For details of [string split function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm)